# Adding a health check path on Prisma docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prisma

I'm hosting my [Prisma docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/prismagraphql/prisma/) on a Kubernetes cluster that requires a health check path to determine whether the container is alive. Since I don't have any control over the endpoints in this container, how would I add a health check route that Kubernetes could hit?

Comment: Prisma provides a [management api](https://www.prisma.io/docs/run-prisma-server/management-api-foe1/). You can use it to query server and project information. One of these may be suitable for health-check purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your prisma container manifest file. If you deploy prisma by a `deployment`, run:

```
$ kubectl edit deployment <prisma_deployment_name> --namespace <namespace>
```

And put the following probe spec in the prisma container spec.

---

```
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 4466
      # Number of seconds after the container has started before probes are initiated.
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      # How often (in seconds) to perform the probe.
      periodSeconds: 10
      # Number of seconds after which the probe times out.
      timeoutSeconds: 60
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 4466
      # Number of seconds after the container has started before probes are initiated.
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      # How often (in seconds) to perform the probe.
      periodSeconds: 10
      # Number of seconds after which the probe times out.
      timeoutSeconds: 60
```